# How to make mouse pointer change to precision with coordinates below it?

Tags: mouse, coordinates

I want my mouse pointer look like this and the same as this in terms of its use - on my Windows.

[image: Select]

The reason why I want it this way, is because I will measure the components from a given web template image.

I have been tweaking, yet when I change my pointer from `Precision`, and tried to drag. There is no coordinates showing up.

**How can I do this on Windows?**

[image: Mouse options]

Answer (score 1):

Here are Two chrome extensions that you might find helpful

---

[Dimensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dimensions/baocaagndhipibgklemoalmkljaimfdj)

You can use this to mesure the size of boxes and gaps between elements.

[image]

---

[Page Ruler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/emliamioobfffbgcfdchabfibonehkme?hl=en)

With Page Ruler you can highlight elements to find their position and size.

[image]
you can also select custom regions aswell
[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I'm receiving an image - web template.

***This is only a suggested answer, since I can't find a perfect way of doing it***.

I just open it with Paint (`mspaint`). And used it's `Rectangular Selection` and get the coordinates below - highlighted with yellow.

[image: Paint]